# Python convert markdown to html fix

Tags: python, markdown

This is my actual code :

```
import bleach
import markdown


html = """
**### The Facebook Campaign will be alligned:**
**### What you get:**
"""


def render_markdown(text):
    if not text:
        return ''

    html = markdown.markdown(text, extensions=[
        'markdown.extensions.sane_lists',
        'markdown.extensions.nl2br',
    ])
    return bleach.clean(html, tags=[
        'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'br', 'h3', 'b', 'strong', 'u', 'i', 'em', 'hr', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'blockquote'
    ])


print render_markdown(html)
```

problem is, same user add more time markdown code like **### What you get:** , the conversion results is this :

```
<p><strong>### The Facebook Campaign will be aligned to your business goal (1 x goal per hour):</strong></p>
<p><strong>### What you get:</strong></p>
```

how could I prevent this situation? i want return clean html code without rimanend markdown code in text, the perfect output is this :

```
<p><strong>The Facebook Campaign will be aligned to your business goal (1 x goal per hour):</strong></p>
<p><strong>What you get:</strong></p>
```

Comment: Doesn't `###` mean something like `<h3>`? Have you tried without the surrounding `**...**`?

Comment: @tobias_k problem is users add more times markdown code, so i want to replace and remain only one, is ok if is h3 or <p>

Comment: It looks like `**### ....**` is just not valid markdown, and you will get the same result using the command line "compiler". You can't have `**` around a heading. You _could_ use `### **...**`, but that's just redundant.

Comment: I guess you _could_ post-process the HTML and check whether any of the text-segments contain typical markdown-symbols...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**### foo**
```

Is actually well parsed and really means:

```
<p><strong>### foo</strong></p>
```

It's not a Python or Markdown issue here, only a user that don't know how to format Markdown..

If you want to clean this you will have to parse user's input - but this is really not a Markdown question here, but a way more generic question that will surely requires some Regex.

---

- For `<h3>Foo</h3>` do `### Foo`
- For `<p><strong>Foo</strong></p>` do `**Foo**`.

---

### Edit because of comments

Ok, so you want to fix this specific case, here is how:

```
import re
string = '**### foo**'

print(re.sub('\*{2}\#+([^*]+)\*{2}', '** \\1 **', string))
```

Output

```
** foo **
```

So, final function:

```
def render_markdown(text):
    if not text:
        return ''

    text = re.sub('\*{2}\#+([^*]+)\*{2}', '** \\1 **', text)
    html = markdown.markdown(text, extensions=[
        'markdown.extensions.sane_lists',
        'markdown.extensions.nl2br',
    ])
    return bleach.clean(html, tags=[
        'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'br', 'h3', 'b', 'strong', 'u', 'i', 'em', 'hr', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'blockquote'
    ])
```

Comment: i am agree with you, is not Markdown issue, but i need to clean the output code, how i can do this ?

Comment: Do you want to clean **this specific case** or all possible errors? (spoiler: second choice is not possible, well not possible in a decent amount of time / efforts)

Comment: only this specific case